# Plotting a list against a list

Tags: plotting

```
l1={1,2,3,4}
l2={5,6,7,8}
```

I want to plot the `l2` against `l1`. that is at value `1` on x axis, it should show value `5`, `6` at value `2` and so on..how can i do that?

Comment: `ListPlot[Transpose@{l1,l2}]`

Comment: @IPoiler that's a legit answer; you should post it as one.

Comment: I'm quite sure this is a dupe.

Comment: @J.M. yep, it is, maybe some additional key words are needed

Comment: Now, **that** didn't show up in my searches. Thanks @Kuba!

Answer (score 4):

`ListPlot` can be used to plot lists of discrete points. The documentation notes that to specify both abscissa, as well as the ordinate, for your points then the supplied list must be of the form $\{\{x_1,y_1\},\dotsc,\{x_n,y_n\}\}$. So we can

```
{l1,l2}
```

to obtain the form $\{\{x_1,\dotsc,x_2\},\{y_1,\dotsc,y_n\}\}$, then transpose it to get the necessary form. In one shot,

```
l1={1,2,3,4}
l2={5,6,7,8}
ListPlot[Transpose@{l1,l2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

To see why `Transpose` dose that job, you can run the following code:

```
l1 = {1, 2, 3, 4} ;
l2 = {5, 6, 7, 8};
{l1, l2} // MatrixForm
l3 = Transpose[{l1, l2}];
l3 // MatrixForm
ListPlot[l3, 
 Joined -> True](*Set to False if you want the discrete points*)
```

Comment: `Joined->False` is the default for `ListPlot`. It does no harm but is not needed.

Comment: @JackLaVigne I just want to show OP an option.